# How to fill a void within a body?

Tags: fusion360

Starting from this sketch:

[image: Sketch showing a curved profile]

I've revolved and extruded it to result in the body shown:

[image: 3D body resulting from revolving and extruding the sketch]

This is destined to be printed, so I need to fill in the cavity of the stick-y-out-y bit. I can use Surface->Patch to make it *look* correct from the outside, but there's still a void within:

[image: Close-up of cavity]

[image: 3D body with hole filled in with a surface patch]

[image: Sectional analysis revealing cavity]

I've searched using phrases such as "fusion join surface to body" "fusion fill void within body" and have only found results talking about making a body exclusively from surfaces. One promising sounding option was "boundary fill", but it seems to have no effect in this case.

What is the correct tool / technique to use here?

Comment: How is this related to 3D printing? For 3D design and modeling questions this is mandatory.

Comment: Just saying you will be printing it will be enough! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simplify the order of operations

Sometimes, it is way easier to do the order of operations in a different order:

First, create the thickness of the body. Only then then subtract the rotation profile and last sweep the the outer profile subtractively

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm still working on my "when to think additively and when to think subtractively" strategy, and this is clearly a case of me taking the wrong route. I _did_ manage to resolve it with my model by turning it into surfaces, deleting some of the inner ones and then stitching it back together, but your strategy would have been much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a tool that can do that (would be very helpful), but you could use boolean operators to do the same!

A simplified version of your product looks like:

[image]

When you create an box , or part of a box of the same height in the part you need to fill the void it will kook like (2 separate bodies in one view):

[image]

Now use a boolean operator "Split Boby":

[image]

You can subtract your shape from the box:

[image]

to get multiple parts (3 parts in this case):

[image]

Now use a boolean operator to glue the parts together (option combine):

[image]

This will give you your filled void:

[image]

Comment: That's the unelegant solution and can fail for very complex bodies

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't require the OP to start over again! 

Comment: you mean modify all bodies before? ;)